# TYPO3 Delete FileReference as non admin

Tags: typo3, settings, typo3-10.x

I can't figure out which setting I have to activate to allow non-admin users to delete file references in the backend.

As admin I have that little trash icon which is missing when logged in as non-admin user.

I set every single flag to allow data manipulation in the backend users module but nothing worked so far. The only option is to give the user admin privileges. What do I miss?

[image: Missing "trash" icon]

Edit:
I am on TYPO3 10.4

Edit:
TCA for field:

```php
'image' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label'   => 'Image',
    'config'  => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
        'image',
        [
            'appearance'           => [
                'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference'
            ],
            'foreign_types'        => [
                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => [
                    'showitem' => '
                    --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                    --palette--;;filePalette'
                ]
            ],
            'foreign_match_fields' => [
                'fieldname'   => 'image',
                'tablenames'  => 'tx_association_domain_model_association',
                'table_local' => 'sys_file',
            ],
            'maxitems'             => 1,
            'minitems'             => 0
        ],
        $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
    ),

],
```

Comment: To what element does this image belong to? To a content element or to a record from an extension?

Comment: @MikelWohlschlegel the image belongs to a record of an own extension.

Comment: Do you have that problem only in your extension or also with image relations e.g. in page properties, content elements or news records? If it's only your extension, can you post the TCA of at image field? And maybe you want to check if there is some weird TSConfig code for sys_file_reference.

Comment: @PeterKraume Thanks for the input, every other field seems to work (mask, page properties) I added the TCA to my question. I searched for weird TSConfig but can't find anything that could my trigger that issue.

Comment: Looks good so far. I assume that you're on the latest 10.4 release (as of writing thats 10.4.15). My next step would be to debug the core to check if it's a bug or configuration.

Comment: I double checked parts of your TCA in 10.4.15, worked for me. As far as I know there is not read / write configuration, which blocks editors to delete file references. Try the following: delete this file reference as admin, add a new file reference with your editor user. Does it behave the same?

Comment: @MikelWohlschlegel I did that and after deleting it with the admin and re-adding the image with an editor It looked good. After re-adding the image with the editor I had my "usual" controlls (include delete). I then gave the editor full access to the whole Fileadmin folder but that also didnt change anything.

Comment: So does it work? Permissions on fileadmin do not affect file relations in this case, as you don't delete the file, just the reference to it.

Comment: It did work for that one single image I deleted using the admin and added again using the editor. But the issue remains for all the other records. It is an image that is uploaded by the frontend via form which means that new "broken" records are created all the time.

Comment: Ah, got it. I would say that your TCA is correct. You should have an look into the creation process of the file reference in the frontend? Maybe compare the DB entries to find any differences?